# Is "connected, simply connected" Redundant?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, connectedness

Here are my definitions of "connected" and "simply connected."

> A topological space $X$ is *connected* if and only if it is not the union of two nonempty disjoint open sets.
>
> A topological space $X$ is *simply connected* if and only if it is path-connected and has trivial fundamental group (i.e. $\pi_1(X)\simeq\{\mathrm{e}\}$ and $|\pi_0(X)|=1$).

It is a classic and elementary exercise in topology to show that, if a space is path-connected, then it is connected. **Thus, if a space is simply connected, then it is connected.**

Yet, despite this implication, I've read several cases where the words "connected, simply connected" appear together.

For example, in Kobayashi and Nomizu's *Foundations of Differential Geometry*, Volume 1, page 252, the following is written: "Let $M$ be a connected, simply connected analytic manifold with an analytic linear connection."

In [this paper on $T^3$ actions](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1997633) and [this paper on rotationally symmetric manifolds](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1999048) (Links to Journal Storage, also known as JSTOR), they use "connected, simply connected" on their first page. The first of these takes it a step further, referring to "closed, compact, connected, simply connected $4$-manifolds," where a closed manifold (unfortunate terminology) is defined as a compact manifold without boundary.

My question is simple: Why use the words "connected, simply connected" when being simply connected implies connectedness?

Thank you.

Comment: I've seen people use "simply connected" to mean that every connected component has trivial fundamental group [don't remember who and where, unfortunately]. In that usage, it isn't redundant.

Comment: Interesting. I would think a term like "component-wise simply connected" would work better. That usage would make sense, though.

Comment: This is an example of unnecessary redundant overdetermination. I do it myself.

Comment: The idea of the fundamental group or the entire homotopy theory is intrinsic to point topological category. Thus $$ \pi_{1} (X) $$ is dependant on base point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think some authors require that "simply connected" only be applied to spaces that are already known to be path connected, and then the definition is that a path connected space is simply connected if its fundamental group is trivial (with some basepoint). [Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-079-01/S0002-9947-1955-0073162-3/S0002-9947-1955-0073162-3.pdf) is an article from 1955 which explicitly uses some version of this convention.

The problem is that if a space is not path connected then there is even more ambiguity than usual about what you mean by taking its fundamental group - now it really matters which path component you pick a basepoint in.